# Computed column of type Date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have parameters column in my db. It contains different params as varchar including "BestBeforeDate". Now I want to be able to filter the rows based on BestBeforeDate. I'm trying to create a computed column of type 'Date' and then index it. I do:

> alter table stocklines add BestBeforeDate as CONVERT(date,
>   JSON_VALUE(Parameters, '$.BestBeforeDate'), 112) persisted

and I'm getting an error: JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 22. but I don't have any dots in my Best BeforeDate json property...[image]

Table Design:
[image]

Comment: Table definitions, sample data? Also, you tagged this with sql 2008 but JSON wasn't available in 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one of my Properties columns containes an invalid Json: "{ Param4: "54"" and then no closing Square bracket... its interresting why the exception said '.' is unexpected character though. There are no any dots in Parameters column for every row...